# Java FX-FXML: Binding an fxml width to a different fxml width

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I have an TabPane FXML file, and when you press a button, it adds a new tab which gets it's content from a different fxml file. How do I bind the width of the tab to the width of the tab pane?

```
@FXML
private void makeNewTab(ActionEvent event) {

    int totalTabs = selectTab.getTabs().size() - 1; // this is the TabPane

    Tab newTab = new Tab();
    newTab.setText("New tab" + totalTabs);
    newTab.setClosable(false);

    try{
    newTab.setContent(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("CoreScenes/NewTabSceneFXML.fxml")));
    }
    catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("Failed to Load 'NewTabSceneFXML.fxml'. Unknown Error.");
    }


    selectTab.getTabs().add(newTab);
}
```

This as it is adds the tab fine, but it doesn't fit it to the width, which is what I need.

Edit 1:

Here is an example from scratch, it might be because i'm using scene building, but I don't know. Setting the size of everything to computed size isn't what I need. What I need is to find out how to bind a sub-fxml file's node to it's parent fxml file's node. So when I resize the screen everything gets resized, but it doesn't seem possible in Scene Builder.

[Does not bind, the stage is too small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjuHi.png)

[When I expand the screen, more of the subtab is revealed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxk1T.png)

Primary FXML:

```
<TabPane fx:id="mainTab" prefHeight="453.0" prefWidth="499.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"  fx:controller="testtabs.FXMLDocumentController">
   <tabs>
      <Tab fx:id="ranTab" text="Untitled Tab 1">
         <content>
            <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="115.0" text="Button" />
         </content>
      </Tab>
   </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

Secondary FXML:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testtabs.FXMLTab2Controller">
   <children>
      <TabPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
               <content>
                  <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <SplitPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                        <ScrollPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                          <content>
                            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                          </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                        <ScrollPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </content></Tab>
          <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2" />
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the secondary fxml:

Without specifying the anchors for children, `AnchorPane` just behaves like a `Pane`, i.e. the children are resized to their preferred size and keep this size regardless of the `AnchorPane` size.

To change this behavior, specify those constraints on the `TabPane` in the secondary fxml:

```xml
<TabPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0">
    ...
</TabPane>
```

Or simpler use `<TabPane>` as root element of the fxml:

```xml
<TabPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testtabs.FXMLTab2Controller">
    ...
</TabPane>
```

---

**Note:** The `HBox` used as content of this `TabPane` won't resize the children to greater widths than the preferred widths, since you didn't use `hgrow` properties other than the default value (`NEVER`). You could also fix this to e.g. always grow the `ScrollPane` like this:

```xml
<HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
   <children>
      <SplitPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      <ScrollPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
        </content>
      </ScrollPane>
      <ScrollPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```